# How to prevent Bash from altering history?

Tags: bash, history

If I press the Up or Down arrows on my keyboard and then modify something from my history, it's changed forever. Even if I press Ctrl-C and then try to bring it up again, it's still changed -- I've lost that entry in my history.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I love the title of this question. *You can actually alter history and you're complaining? What is wrong with you?!*

Comment: @Daniel: Lol, yeah... I mean, it's as if I'm changing my past. Clearly nonsensical, and it gets *ridiculously* annoying after a while. :\

Comment: Btw, [if you use history-search-xxx](http://superuser.com/questions/225799/bash-per-command-history-how-does-it-work/225808#225808) instead, the behavior's different. Maybe that's something for you?

Comment: @Daniel: That's indeed useful -- thanks a lot. But still, I'd like to know the answer to this question, because sometimes the commands don't look so much like each other, and that doesn't work.

Comment: history-search with an empty prompt works just like regular history prev/next, i.e. displaying all entries.

Comment: @Daniel: That's a way to bypass the problem, but it's not really a solution -- I've bound the two searches to different commands, and I don't want *either* of them to change my history.

Comment: Related to https://superuser.com/questions/1131241/bash-history-editing-unwanted

Comment: This is rather strange, on my machine `Ctrl-C` actually aborts the changes...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want the readline setting:

```
set revert-all-at-newline on
```

You can either put it in `~/.inputrc` (see note below), or put `bind 'revert-all-at-newline on'` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Demo:

```
$ man bash
$ bind 'set revert-all-at-newline on'
$ man bsh # up arrow and edit
No manual entry for bsh
$ man bash # three up arrows
```

Further details are in the [Bash manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-revert_002dall_002dat_002dnewline):

> `revert-all-at-newline`
>
> If set to ‘`on`’, Readline will undo all changes to history lines before returning when accept-line is executed. By default, history lines may be modified and retain individual undo lists across calls to readline. The default is ‘`off`’.

---

> ***Note:***
>
> If a new `~/.inputrc` file is created for the purpose of setting `revert-all-at-newline`, be aware that bash will use the readline settings in this file ***instead of*** any settings which may be in the file `/etc/inputrc`.  That is, any settings specified in `/etc/inputrc` will no longer be in effect.  Therefore, if the `/etc/inputrc` file exists, it's a good idea to start `~/.inputrc` with the line:
>
> `$include /etc/inputrc`

Comment: You're awesome, that's exactly what I need. No longer do I want to punch my monitor. :D +1000000 (I wish)

Answer (score 5):

I enter:

```
ls /tmp
```

- wonderful. Now I wan't to enter

```
ls /temp
```

and can prevent it to enter the history, therefore prevent it to overwrite ls /tmp, if I start the command with a blank:

```
 ls /temp
```

It's hard to see, but if you know it ...

It is controlled by

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

ignoredups only ignores duplicated commands, ignoreboth ignores spaces at the beginning of line, which is useful, to hide otherwise unhidden passwords.

But maybe you're out for a solution, where you end with both commands, the unmodified old one, and the new one. My version of bash or settings behave like this, but I don't know, what's different to yours.

Comment: Ha; I always assumed not saving commands with a leading space was a bug. Thanks. :)