# Bash history editing unwanted

Tags: bash, history

This happens. Typing:

```
$ qwer
$ asdf
$ zxcv
```

up-arrow twice, backspace, backspace, down-arrow twice, then:

```
$ history 4
  519  qwer
  520* as
  521  zxcv
  522  history 4
```

The star by `520` tells me it's an intended feature.

I do not know how to control this kind of history editing. It has been in the way many more times than it has helped me, and I would like to disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Bash from altering history?](https://superuser.com/questions/302230/how-to-prevent-bash-from-altering-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). To change it you need to add `set revert-all-at-newline on` to your `/etc/inputrc` (or `~/.inputrc`) if you have it. Note that you don't even have to start a new subshell after modifying `inputrc` because you can invoke `re-read-init-file` function which is binded to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> by default:

```
$ bind -p | grep read
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```